# Is service fabric compatible with .netstandard2.0 or .netcore2.0

Tags: azure-service-fabric, .net-standard-2.0

I have a set of service projects that i build about 12 months ago.  I've tried updating nuget packages as often as possible but with .netstandard and core 2.0 I assumed it would be ready to port to the new sdk and packages without too much trouble.

I've managed to update most of my libraries to .netstandard2.0 but any of the services using service fabric packages won't work.

I've had to default my libraries to 4.6.2

I've tried by updating the csproj to use the new style layout.  I've also tried by creating a new service fabric project, selecting the .net core option template and copy the settings from there but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Service Fabric is compatible with .netstandard 2.0 and .net core 2.0 (where the project is actually netcore2.0 and not net462) but with this 2 conditions:

- [Visual studio 2017 15.5](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/) (only in preview as of now)
- [Service Fabric Tools 2.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/7/3/A737BB0E-C5A9-49E7-AB49-E59FB5B35FF2/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Vsix.Alpha.vsix) (only in preview as of now)

The good news is that you can create the project/solution from the preview version and then reopen it from the regular version and it will work.

[Here's](https://github.com/cheesemacfly/ServiceFabricWebApplication) an example of such a solution